# How to use 'tr' to find and replace only ---

Tags: bash, tr, kustomize

So, I have an output from a command (`kustomize build`) and I want to convert the `---` in the output to `###`. For example:

```
$ kustomize build
apiVersion: extensions/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  labels:
    app: hello-world
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  ports:
  - name: service
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  type: NodePort
```

and I want to change it to :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  labels:
    app: hello-world
###
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  ports:
  - name: service
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  type: NodePort
```

I tried `$ kustomize build | tr '\---' '#'` but that replaces every instance of even a single `'-'` to `'#'`. I even tried `tr '[-]{3}' '#'` but even that didn't help. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: `tr` is just simply a wrong tool for this

Comment: Why do you want to remove the standard YAML document marker and replace it with a comment?

Comment: actually, i figured a way to get around that now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` only translates single characters (and removes them, if you specify that).

What you need to use is the "stream editor" `sed` which can replace groups of characters:

```
sed 's/---/###/g'
```

Comment: Depending on whether `------` should be replaced by `######` or not, it may be relevant to use `sed 's/^---$/###/g'`

Comment: @mouviciel More importantly, the bare string `---` could occur in lots of contexts other than that of document marker.

Comment: (And even then, `^---$` could match a line in a multiline string. Simply put, `sed` isn't really up to the task of editing YAML in general.)

Comment: @chepner OP never specified that the input is YAML ;-)